# How to count number of spaces just after the date information?

Tags: r

I have unstructured data that look like this:

```
data <- c("24-March-2017      product 1              color 1",
"March-2017-24              product 2                 color 2",
"2017-24-March  product 3              color 3")
```

I would like to count number of spaces between the date and the first character (product column) for each line. As shown in the sample data, the date format can vary. This information will be used to put the data into structured format.

What is the best way to perform this in R? I believe `gsub` can be used in this case, just not sure how to apply to count only number of spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: its worth noting that you could bypass counting the spaces and just substitute anything greater than one space with a comma. That will let you  split the string and allow coercion to a data.frame etc.

Comment: @ zacdav- thanks for the comment unfortunately the data I have could have more than one consecutive space in each field so this won't work. I provided the example above to simplify.

Comment: it may have been helpful to not simplify in that case as there may be easier ways to solve that problem directly.

Comment: agree, that was my thought after posting the question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach would be to use `regexpr` that will return information about the first match of a given regular expression. In your case, you are looking for the first instance of a repeated white space. So, the following would tell you (1) where in your string you'll find the first white spaces, and (2) in the attributes how many white spaces you have:

```
regexpr("\\s+", data)
# [1] 14 14 14
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1]  6 14  2
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
```

You can then use `attr` to extract the `match.length` attribute:

```
attr(regexpr("\\s+", data), "match.length")
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @xehpuk, using `\\s+` will match at least one space. If your date column contained spaces that could be problematic. Instead you'd need to use `\\s{2,}`.

Comment: Your regex will find the first instance of **at least one** white space, not necessarily repeated.

Answer (score 7):

You can sub out that section, then take the number of characters.

```
nchar(sub("\\S+(\\s+).*", "\\1", data))
# [1]  6 14  2
```

Or this one is kinda fun:

```
nchar(data) - nchar(sub("\\s+", "", data))
# [1]  6 14  2
```

Answer (score 3):

Same solution using `gregexpr` as the above but in one line:

```
vapply(gregexpr(" +",dat),function(x)attr(x,"match.length")[1],0)
## [1]  6 14  2
```

I am assuming that the date is always is coming at the begining.

Comment: yes, the date is always coming at the beginning. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `stringi` approach to get the output

```
library(stringi)
m1 <- stri_locate(data, regex = "\\s+")
m1[,2] -m1[,1] + 1
#[1]  6 14  2
```